# How do i save strings to an array and display the strings in an label?

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios7

I'm a rookie at iOS and Objective-C programming, trying (HARD) to learn it, so i've enrolled in a basic course. I'm trying to implement two `IBAcion`s in my ViewController.m file but i seem to have problems regarding my way of thinking about this problem and the difficulties understanding the scope, e.g what i can and cannot call and such.

One of this `IBAction`s will throw a dice, getting the right images, and another that will save the outcome and display the latest 10 throws.

Please do not get discouraged by what seems to be a lot of code.

These are the following properties i've declared in the `@interface`(.h file)

```
@interface ViewController : UIViewController

@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIImageView *dieOne;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIImageView *dieTwo;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *latestTenThrows;

@property (nonatomic) NSUInteger dieValue1;
@property (nonatomic) NSUInteger dieValue2;
@property (nonatomic) NSUInteger totalValue;

@property (nonatomic) NSMutableArray *rolledDiceArray;
@property (nonatomic) NSMutableString *rolledDiceString;
@end
```

And this is my implementation

```
- (IBAction)throwDice {

NSMutableArray *dieArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithObjects:
                            @"one", @"two", @"three", @"four", @"five", @"six", nil];

NSUInteger dieIndex1 = arc4random_uniform(6);
NSUInteger dieIndex2 = arc4random_uniform(6);

UIImage *image1 = [UIImage imageNamed:[dieArray objectAtIndex:dieIndex1]];
UIImage *image2 = [UIImage imageNamed:[dieArray objectAtIndex:dieIndex2]];

self.dieOne.image = image1;
self.dieTwo.image = image2;
```

So far so good, the right images are showing but here is where it gets tricky for me. I am trying to "save" the rolled dices value and show them in a lable like this: 5 + 2 = 7 in the view, and it should diplay the latest 10 throws.

```
self.dieValue1 = (dieIndex1+1);
self.dieValue2 = (dieIndex2+1);
self.totalValue = self.dieValue1 + self.dieValue2;

NSMutableString *rolledDiceString = [[NSMutableString alloc] init];

[rolledDiceString appendString:[NSString stringWithFormat:
                                 @"%d + %d = %d",
                                 self.dieValue1,self.dieValue2,self.totalValue]];
```

How will i get permission to this array in my other functicion, `- (IBAction)saveThrow{}` below?

```
NSMutableArray *rolledDiceArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
[rolledDiceArray addObject:rolledDiceString];
```

If i add this NSLog call i will only get 1, no matter how many times i hit "Roll dice" in the interface", which means that when i hit "Roll dice" in the interface it's not putting the values, created into a string, in the array correctly. 
How do i add the strings correctly to my array so that i later can retrieve that information from another IBAction? And do i have permission to this array in my function below?

```
NSLog(@"%d",rolledDiceArray.count);
} // End for -(IBAction)throwDice{
```

In my second and last IBAction, i'm trying to add the strings to the label, but having issues here since my array doesn't getting the strings.

```
- (IBAction)saveThrow {
NSMutableArray *savedThrowsArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

[savedThrowsArray addObject:self.rolledDiceArray];

self.latestTenThrows.text = [// Latest 10 items (strings) in savedThrowsArray];
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't flail; think what you are doing. Your words (in your code) have *meaning*. The computer can only do what you tell it to do...! So, let's look:

```
NSMutableArray *rolledDiceArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
[rolledDiceArray addObject:rolledDiceString];
```

Every time you run that code, you are creating a completely new empty mutable array (that is what `= [[NSMutableArray alloc] init]` means in the first line). Therefore *no matter how many times you run it*, the resulting array will contain only *one* object (the object you add in the second line with `addObject`).

```
NSMutableArray *savedThrowsArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
[savedThrowsArray addObject:self.rolledDiceArray];
```

Same deal.

And meanwhile, you've got these *completely different* instance variable sitting unused:

```
@property (nonatomic) NSMutableArray *rolledDiceArray;
@property (nonatomic) NSMutableString *rolledDiceString;
```

But none of your code *ever* talks to / about them. They are just sitting there going to waste. You need to initialize them and put your data in them - not in these local automatic variables that you keep creating and throwing away.

Answer (score 0):

I think the error is here:

```
NSMutableString *rolledDiceString = [[NSMutableString alloc] init];
```

this creates a variable local to the method which overrides the class property. So when it goes out of scope (i.e. the method returns) it is deallocated.
Simply replace with

```
self.rolledDiceString = [[NSMutableString alloc] init];
```

and the same happens for the array - you should allocate it once (in init or viewDidLoad) and just use

```
[self.rolledDiceArray addObject:self.rolledDiceString];
```